# line replace given contexts on two sides of a split

Tags: bash, awk, replace, split

I am trying to do a line replace given contexts on two sides of a split. This seems much easier to do in python but my entire pipeline is in bash so I would love to stick to tools like sed, awk, grep, etc.

For example:

```
split_0 = split('\t')[0]
split_1 = split('\t')[1]
if (a b c in split_0 AND w x y z in split_1):
    split_1 = split_1.replace('w x y z', 'w x_y z')
```

I can use awk to do splits like this:

```
awk -F '\t' '{print$1}'
```

But I don't know how to do this on both sides simultaneously in order to satisfy both conditions.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example input/output:
This is an example and I have many rules like this but basically what I want to do here is given an example where I have "ex" on the left side and "ih g z" on the right side, I want to make a substitution with ih g z going to ih g_z.

```
input: exam    ih g z ae m
output: exam    ih g_z ae m
```

I could do a brutal sed like:

```
sed 's/\(.*ex.*\t.*\)ih g z\(.*\)/\1ih g_z\2/g'
```

but this seems ugly and I am sure there is a much better way to do this.  *I am not totally sure if the "\t" works that way in sed.

Comment: Can you give us some example input/output?

Comment: @ Mr Llama, updated!

Comment: @Ed Morton I think it might be better if I explained the example better. But I think the question is pretty clear.  This is not a simple substitution but rather a substitution on one side given conditions on both sides.

Comment: not sure why my question was downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F'\t' '$1~/ex/ && $2~/ih g z/{sub("g z","g_z")}1' file
```

conditions on fields 1 and 2 separated by tab delimiter, replace string (once).

If you have a bunch of these replacement rules, it's better to not hard code them in the script

```
    $ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{lr[NR]=$1; rr[NR]=$2; 
                                      ls[NR]=$3; rs[NR]=$4; next}
                                     {for(i=1; i<=length(lr); i++) 
                                         if($1~lr[i] && $2~rr[i])
                                            {gsub(ls[i],rs[i],$2);
                                             print; 
                                             next}}1' rules file

111     2b2b2b
222     333u33u
4       bbb5az
9       nochange
```

where

```
$ head rules file
==> rules <==
1       2       a       b
2       3       z       u
4       5       e       b

==> file <==
111     2a2a2a
222     333z33z
4       eee5az
9       nochange
```

Noticed that replacement will be for the first applicable rule on second field only and multiple times.  Both files need to be tab delimited.

Comment: I like this.  It is better than my sed.  Out of curiosity, how could I negate with awk, can I use "^"?  In case I have a conflict like if I had exs on the left side I would want to negate it.

Comment: `$1!~/ex/` is the pattern match negation.

Comment: I noticed one issue.  I have several substitutions to make.  can I concatenate these clauses?  I thought about creating tmp files but that seems messy and I am sure there is a slicker way to do it.

Comment: several subs for the same conditions? chain them in the block `sub();sub();...`, for different conditions just add other `condition{action}` blocks

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.  I will have always the same separator just different things in context 1 and 2 where substitutions need to be made.

Comment: say I have these three: awk -F'\t' '$1~/ex/ && $2~/ih gg zz/{sub("gg zz","gg_zz")}1';

awk -F'\t' '$1~/xs/ && $2~/kk ss ih zz/{sub("kk ss ih zz","kk_ss ih_zz")}1';

awk -F'\t' '$1~/x/ && $1!~/ks/ && $1!~/ex/ && $2~/eh kk ss/{sub("eh kk ss","eh_kk_ss")}1';

Comment: that is what I was looking for.  I like them not hard coded!  Very cool!